# Creating a right-to-left Excel file with Java

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I'm using jxl to create excel files. I need those files to be right to left, but I can't find out how to set it to be this way.

Comment: Have you tried setting the [regional settings](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/WorkbookSettings.html#setExcelRegionalSettings%28java.lang.String%29) with a country code like `SA`?

Comment: I tried to set it to SA, and some other country codes, but it writes "Warning:  Unknown country code US using UK", and doesn't do anything different.